# How to update an array that's linked to a List<string>

Tags: c#, custom-fields

So I'm working on this project and I'm really new to programming. I'm trying to make a Hangman game using C# and I'm a little stuck. I can display everything just fine to the console but when it comes to guessing the word, which is CRYPTOZOOLOGY, I can't get the underscores to change to the correct letter if the user's guess is actually within the word. So right now if the user guesses 'C' then the game will keep asking the user to choose a letter. This is not what I want. What I'm trying to get to is once the user guesses the correct letter I want the underscores to update to reveal the correct letter and the 'Used Letters: ' to reflect the letter that have been used in total. I believe my issue might be a hierarchy problem but I've been working on this for a couple of hours and at this point I'm pretty frustrated. I wish I could make this question more simple to answer but I don't feel like I have much of a choice. My code is listed below. Thanks.

*****Update*****:
I added a while loop so the code can be run from the top once everything is done in the body. I've cleared the console after the user makes a selection. My issue now is outputting the letter in the correct spot where the underscore is.

*****Update*****: I was able to add the letter 'C' to the beginning of the underscores. Now if I type in 'R' the used Letters list will show the letters I've used but even if it's the right letter it won't update the underscores.

```
        public void GameDisplay(int randomNumber, Dictionary<string, string> randomKeyValue)
        {
            bool gameRunning = true;
            if (randomNumber == 0)
            {
                // Displaying the title
                Console.WriteLine("===================================");
                Console.WriteLine("              HANGMAN          ");
                Console.WriteLine("===================================");

                while (gameRunning)
                {

                    // Pulling the definition based on the Key of the word Dictionary
                    string randomDefinition = randomKeyValue["CRYPTOZOOLOGY"];

                    string associatedWord = "CRYPTOZOOLOGY";


                    string[] arrWord = { "C", "R", "Y", "P", "T", "O", "Z", "O", "O", "L", "O", "G", "Y" };

                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nDefinition: {0}\r\n", randomDefinition);


                       for (int i = 0; i < arrWord.Length; i++)
                    {
                     
                        if (_guesses.Contains(arrWord[i])) 
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0} ", _guesses[i]);

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("__ ");
                        }
                    }



                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n------------------------------------\r\n");


                    Console.WriteLine("Used Letters: ");

                    foreach (string miss in _misses)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0} ", miss);
                    }



                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n========================================\r\n");


                    bool winning = false;


                    if (winning == false)
                    {

                        while (!winning)
                        {
                            GuessAgain(_guesses, _misses, arrWord, associatedWord);
                            AllMisses(_guesses);
                            Console.Clear();
                            winning = true;
                        }

                        /*Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                        _guesses.Clear();
                        winning = false;
                        */
                    }
                    else if (_guesses.Contains("C") && _guesses.Contains("R") && _guesses.Contains("Y") && _guesses.Contains("P") && _guesses.Contains("T") && _guesses.Contains("O") && _guesses.Contains("Z") && _guesses.Contains("L") && _guesses.Contains("G") && _guesses.Contains("Y"))
                    {

                        while (!winning)
                        {
                            GuessAgain(_guesses, _misses, arrWord, associatedWord);
                            AllMisses(_guesses);
                            Console.Clear();
                            winning = true;
                        }

                        // Console.WriteLine("Game over...");

                    }


                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
            // INSTRUCTIONS
            // display each letter in the word and replace with an underscore if its not within guesses


            // While the user has not won or misses 6 times
            // Call a method to display the misses
            // Call a method to allow the player to guess and make sure to validate against repeats

            // Display win/lose hangman message

        }


        public static bool AllMisses(List<string> misses)
        {
            bool winning = false;

            if (misses.Count == 6)
            {
                winning = true;
            }

            return winning;
        }

        public static void GuessAgain(List<string> guesses, List<string> misses, string[] arrWord, string actualWord)
        {

              Console.WriteLine("Choose a letter:");

            string userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            string userGuessCaps = userGuess.ToUpper();

            while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userGuess))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please do not leave this blank.");
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a letter.");
                userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arrWord.Length; i++)
            {
                if (userGuessCaps == arrWord[i] )
                {
                    guesses.Add(userGuessCaps);
                    break;
                }
                else if (userGuessCaps != arrWord[i]) 
                {
                    misses.Add(userGuessCaps);
                    AllMisses(misses);
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a working solution.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string associatedWord = "CRYPTOZOOLOGY";
    List<string> arrWord = new List<string>() { "C", "R", "Y", "P", "T", "O", "Z", "O", "O", "L", "O", "G", "Y" };

    List<string> _guesses = new List<string>();
    List<string> _misses = new List<string>();
    bool winning = false;

    while (!winning)
    {

        Console.Clear();

        // Displaying the title
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");
        Console.WriteLine("              HANGMAN          ");
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");

        // Iterate through each letter in arrWord and display Correct Guesses or __ for not discovered letters
        foreach (string letter in arrWord)
        {
            // Print either the correctly guessed letter or __ for not guessed yet.
            if (_guesses.Contains(letter))
                Console.Write(" " + letter + " ");
            else
                Console.Write("__ ");
        }
                
        // Print all the letters that have been missed.
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n------------------------------------\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Used Letters: " + string.Join(" ", _misses));
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n========================================\r\n");
            
        // Run the method to guess the letter.
        GuessAgain(_guesses, _misses, arrWord, associatedWord);

        // If misses == 6 or if you guessed all the letters, exit.
        winning = AllMisses(_misses) || arrWord.Where(x => _guesses.Contains(x)).Count() == arrWord.Count();
    }

    if (arrWord.Where(x => !_guesses.Contains(x)).Count() > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("LOST");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("WON");
}

public static bool AllMisses(List<string> misses)
{
    // No need to use extra variables to see if the misses count has reached 6
    return misses.Count == 6;
}

public static void GuessAgain(List<string> guesses, List<string> misses, List<string> arrWord, string actualWord)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a letter:");

    string userGuess = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); // Change user's input to upper case

    while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userGuess))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please do not leave this blank.");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a letter.");
        userGuess = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); // Change user's input to upper case
    }

    // Only add the letter to "ONE" of the lists. either it was a guess or a miss. Your code adds 12 letters at a time.. not what you want.
    // You can also add checks to see if the letter has already been guessed before or not.
    if (arrWord.Contains(userGuess))
        guesses.Add(userGuess);

    else
        misses.Add(userGuess);
}
```

---

**Things I found with your code that needed a bit of a change**

1. Use List for arrWord... Makes things easier with Linq queries.
2. One loop to go over the entire Code... you can make a method of it as well, but multiple while loops and for loops were found to be unneeded.
3. *See the comments in the code for changes*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try to make these changes but for 
```winning = AllMisses(_misses) || arrWord.Where(x => _guesses.Contains(x)).Count() > 0)```
I'm getting the error **'Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int''**
and for the ```if (arrWord.Where(x => !_guesses.Contains(x).Count() > 0))``` section, I'm getting the error **'Operator ! cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'**

Comment: @Brookerino For your first error, the last `)` shouldn't be there. Right after `> 0` it should be `;`, the statement is already complete. But if you change it that way, the loop immediately exit on first match, and the player always lost that way.

Comment: @Bookerino You didnt copy paste the line properly... parenthesis are misplaced

Comment: @Brookerino For your second error, you miss the second `)` after `Contains(x)`, you'll also have to remove the last `)`

Comment: I tested this code a few times and ran the way it should.

Comment: Got it. Fixed my issues! Now to test this real quick

Comment: Copy paste this line, `if (arrWord.Where(x => !_guesses.Contains(x)).Count() > 0)`. Parenthesis are misplaced. Last parenthesis goes before the count method

Comment: Okay so it started to work for a moment. I first typed in 'C' and it was added to the list of underscores correctly. When I typed in 'R' it was not added to the list of underscores but it was added to the list of Used Letters. Then I continued to type out the word one letter at a time with each letter being added to the Used Letter section and not the underscores. I eventually lost. Which I'm glad to see that that part actually worked!

Comment: If arrWord is always derived from associatedWord, you can use `var arrWord = associatedWord.Select(Char.ToString).ToList();` instead. That way you only need to modify associatedWord when needed.

Comment: Added a screenshot on how it works when i run the code I posted.

Comment: @Jawad thanks for the screenshot. Weird that it's working for you and not for me. I'll try to restart my Visual Studio program and see if it's just the console being weird.

Comment: @Martheen I tried to change the current List<string> arrWord to what you wrote and I'm still receiving the same issue where it doesn't register that the letter I'm typing is the correct letter. It will just add the next letter to the list of Used Letters

Comment: @Brookerino you can replace var with List<string>. Also, check the rest of the code as well to make sure you check all the changes I made. Update the `GuessAgain` method correctly.

Comment: Oh geez...I figured out why it wasn't registering my input. So good news. It works! But ONLY if I type my guess in a capital letter.

**Update**: I fixed that too. I just converted the user answer to a new string that takes in the answer and changes it to uppercase. @Jawad & Martheen, thank you for you help! I can't express enough how appreciative I am. I've spent, no joke, 8 hours on this project. Thank you thank you!!!

Comment: @Brookerino That is an easy fix. In GuessAgain method, change the line where you read user's guess to this, `string userGuess = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();`. Use ToUpper() to use uppercase letter regardless of what user typed. Also do that in the while loop where you ask user to enter something. **Updated code to reflect this change**

Answer (score 0):

I like Hangman!  Thanks for the "homework".

Here's another approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string word = "CRYPTOZOOLOGY";

    bool result = PlayHangman(word);
    Console.WriteLine();
    if (result)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed my word: " + word);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You ran out of tries!");
        Console.WriteLine("The word was: " + word);
    }

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool PlayHangman(string word, int maxMisses = 6)
{
    int misses = 0;
    string wordToGuess = word.ToUpper();
    StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder(new string('_', wordToGuess.Length));
    string validLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string availableLetters = validLetters;
    while (currentWord.ToString() != wordToGuess && misses < maxMisses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Guesses Left: " + (maxMisses - misses));
        Console.WriteLine("Word: " + currentWord.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Available Letters: " + availableLetters);
        Console.Write("Your guess: "); ;
        string guess = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
        if (guess.Length == 1 && validLetters.Contains(guess))
        {
            if (availableLetters.Contains(guess))
            {
                int letterFound = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(wordToGuess.Substring(i,1) == guess)
                    {
                        currentWord[i] = guess.ToCharArray()[0];
                        letterFound++;
                    }
                }
                availableLetters = availableLetters.Replace(guess, "");
                if (letterFound == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(guess + " was not in the word!");
                    misses++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(guess + " was found " + letterFound + " time" + (letterFound>1 ? "s" : "") + "!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You already tried that letter!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    return (misses < maxMisses);
}
```

Comment: Ooooo, thanks for a different way to make that happen! I like how clean this is. Thank you for your solution to this!

Comment: No problemo.  Enjoy.